# Cron: Permission denied on everything

Tags: linux, permissions, cron

As a regular user I can't edit my cron settings.
I get a "permission denied" for everything: listing the cron commands or editing them.

Example:

```
cron -l
cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied

crontab -e
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/skerit: Permission denied
```

These are the permissions of /var/run/crond.pid:

```
-rwxr-Sr-- 1 root root 5 2011-05-27 12:44 crond.pid
---------- 1 root root 0 2011-03-23 21:13 crond.reboot
```

And the permissions of /var/spool/cron/:

```
drwxr-sr-x  5 root root     4,0K 2009-12-23 23:01 cron
```

All users are also added to the /etc/groups file:

```
crontab:x:102:skerit,www-data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a messy problem.

I ended up adding all the users to the crontab group, and setting the group ownership of all needed files to that crontab group.

A lot of permissions were messed up. Changing the group ownership to something else first "resets" those permissions.

The crontab executable:
`sudo chgrp crontab /usr/bin/crontab`
`sudo chmod g+s /usr/bin/crontab`
Result: `-rwxrwsr-x 1 root crontab 37K 2010-04-15 08:51 /usr/bin/crontab`

The cron spool files:
`sudo chmod 4774 -R /var/spool/cron`
Result: `drwsrwsr--  5 root crontab  4,0K 2009-12-23 23:01 cron`

The cron files in these spool directories need to be READ AND WRITE only. Otherwise they won't run.
`sudo chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`

The cron pid file:
`sudo chmod 744 /var/run/crond.pid`

I think that should cover it.

Comment: I also needed to `chmod -R g+s /var/spool/cron` to achieve the result as shown.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions for the CRON files are set to user root group root, so you'll need to be root to modify or run CRON files. Alternatively you can log in as root and change the groups to something else so you can edit it.

Comment: Oh, really? Shouldn't it be solved then by setting the group ownership to crontab, which my users are members of? (Which also does not work)

Comment: Only if the files are owned by the crontab group, the snippets you posted show it being owned by the 'root' group.

Answer (score 1):

What linux distro is this? Is there an /etc/cron.allow or /etc/cron.deny file? If so, what are their contents?

What are the permissions on 
`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/skerit`

Any user should be able to edit their own crontab.

Comment: I had a ton of problems. The permissions on the skerit file in crontabs was, indeed, wrong. But the permission of the spool directories and the crontab executable were also wrong. I fixed it now