# Running 'cron -f' as an unpriviledged user in docker: /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, docker, cron

I want to create a docker container with a node application which runs on a schedule. I'm attempting to have `cron` running in the foreground in the container and periodically start the application.

My problem is that I want to use the [recommended user](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#non-root-user) `node` which has limited permissions. Running this simple image:

```
FROM node:8-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN mkdir /test \
    && chown node:node /test
ADD cron-test /etc/cron.d/cron-test
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-test    
USER node
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-test
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

where `cron-test` looks like:

```
*   *   *   *   *   echo "running as $(whoami)" >> /test/test.log
--empty line--
```

Results in:

```
$ docker run -v <path on host>:/test:rw test -c 'cron -f'
cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied
```

Removing the switch to `USER node` in `Dockerfile` and running it as above creates a file `/test/test.log` and starts printing `running as root` to it.

Is it possible to run `cron -f` as an unprivileged user? Or would another approach be better?

I could, for example change the cron-job to be:

```
*   *   *   *   *  su - node -c 'echo "running as $(whoami)" >> /test/test.log'
--empty line--
```

And remove `USER node` from the `Dockerfile` permanently. Which would enable me to do `npm start` as the `node` user, but I'm not sure whether this would be ok (as in: 'inline with best pratices') as the default user of the image would still be `root`?

I've also tried to make sure the permissions on cron related files, as per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/274461/412655), were correct but it didn't seem to have any effect. Creating the `crond.pid` file, and setting permissions directly on it, didn't seem like a great idea. Setting permissions like this is quite new to me so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: There are many other ways to run containers on a schedule. An Internet search will give you several ideas. You might find something else a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Even if I need to schedule within the container? Perhaps I'll have to modify my search terms

Comment: Are you sure they need to be in the same container? Perhaps they just need to share a data volume.

Comment: Well the scheduling need to happen within a container, not necessarily the container where the node application is running.